# Sharepoint API: Can get all metadata (likes, views) but NOT comments

Tags: http, sharepoint

I have an old flow that used to work 14 months ago that retrieved views, likes and comments via the SharePoint API.

However, now I cannot get the comments any more (likes and views are just fine), no matter what I try - I do not get an error, but just an empty "results" array (see below).

Here is what I'm trying:

**_api/lists/getbytitle('SitePages')/items(47)/Comments**

**_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site Pages')/GetItemById(47)/Comments**

Here's what I am getting:

HTTP 200 ok, but:

```
    {
      "d": {
        "results": []
      }
    }
```

P.S.: It's NOT "SitePages" that's the issue as I can pull all other information for this item bar "Comments"

Hope you guys can help me out here, and any links to REALLY good Sharepoint API is also appreciated - I usually work my way through the JSON responses that I receive in return, but if there is some hidden super-douper MS documentation available anywhere then please let me know ;-)